# Page view refers to id, whil path is not asking for one

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to load a default django page. Nothing fancy. However, the error I get, hints at an id that is incorrectly set.

> "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'zoekboek'."

The confusing things here (I am a django beginner, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is not confusing at all for you):

- the path for this page in the urls.py is not asking for an id.
- the view is not querying anything yet (I found some posts that had similar errors,
  but related to a filter).
- the debug info points to another view that indeed is requesting an id.
- when I add a slash at the beginning of the path, the error is gone!

**The code**

urls.py

```js
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.scholen, name='scholen'),
    path('<school_id>', views.school_detail, name='school_detail'),
    path('<school_id>/<groep_id>', views.school_groep, name='school_groep'),
    path('<school_id>/<groep_id>/<UserProfile_id>', views.leerling_page, name='leerling_page'),
    path('zoekboek', views.zoekboek, name='zoekboek'),

]
```

views.py

```js
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404

from books.models import Book, Rating
from .models import School, Groep
from profiles.models import UserProfile, Hobby, Sport
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.

def scholen(request):
    """
    Homepage for participating
    schools.
    """
    scholen = School.objects.all()

    context = {
        'scholen': scholen, 
    }
    
    return render(request, 'schools/school_landing.html', context)


def school_detail(request, school_id):
    """
     Details of individual schools.
    """
    school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=school_id)
    groep = Groep.objects.filter(school=school)

    context = {

        'school': school,
        'groep': groep,
    }

    return render(request, 'schools/school_detail.html', context)


def school_groep(request, school_id, groep_id):
    """
     Details of groep.
    """
    school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=school_id)
    groep = get_object_or_404(Groep, pk=groep_id)
    a = groep.naam
    kinderen = UserProfile.objects.filter(groep=a)
    
    context = {

        'school': school,
        'groep': groep,
        'kinderen': kinderen,
    }

    return render(request, 'schools/school_groep.html', context)


def leerling_page(request, school_id, groep_id, UserProfile_id):
    """
    Personal page of school kids.
    """
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=UserProfile_id)

    # If viewer is owner of page, viewer can edit
    owner = False

    if request.user == profile.user:
        owner = True
        
    context = {
        
        'profile': profile,
        'owner': owner,

        }

    return render(request, 'schools/leerling_page.html', context)


def zoekboek(request):
    """
    Page for kids to search their favorite book
    """
    
    
    context = {

    }

    return render(request, 'schools/zoek_boek.html', context)
```

Is this enough information?

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: Simple fix: move `path('zoekboek', views.zoekboek, name='zoekboek'),` from the last place to the second place in your urls

Comment: @Ralf Wow, that did the trick! I did not know that the order of the paths is important. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: move `path('zoekboek', views.zoekboek, name='zoekboek'),` from the last place to the second place in your urls.

Why?

Because Django URLs are resolved using regular expressions; the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) say here in point 3:

> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against `path_info`.

Since your URL path `path('<school_id>', views.school_detail, name='school_detail'),` is very generic, it matches any string including the string `zoekboek`; so the request to `zoekboek` falls into the second line in your URL conf and gets routed to the view `school_detail()` and a `school_id` is expected for that view.

---

Suggestion: to make the URL handling easier and so you can order the URL paths however you like, you could change the URL a bit and add a prefix (for example `school/`) so that not any string matches the URL paths. For example, this schould work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ...),
    path('school/<school_id>', ...),
    path('school/<school_id>/<groep_id>', ...),
    path('school/<school_id>/<groep_id>/<UserProfile_id>', ...),
    path('zoekboek', ...),

]
```

Comment: Great explanation. I guess I need to start using regular expressions :) Thanks!